# Saving Form data dynamically

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code to save the e-mails entered in the form. But on clicking on "Submit", it is giving an internal server error. Please help in rectifying it.

Code for form.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="email_script.php" method="POST">
<p> Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" size="30"/> </p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</body>
</html>

Code for email_script.php:

<? php
$email = $_POST('email');
$file = "file.html"
file_put_contents($file, $email . PHP_EQL, FILE_APPEND);
print("...");
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have a gap between `<?` and `php`. This should be `<?php`.

Also, `$email = $_POST('email');` should be `$email = $_POST['email'];` (with square brackets)

Also, as pointed out below, the second line needs a semi colon at the end.

Also, I have never heard of `PHP_EQL`. Perhaps you mean `PHP_EOL`?

If you are working in a local environment, consider putting `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your php file (after the `<?php`). This will give more detailed errors than just 'Internal Server Error'. BUT REMEMBER to remove the line before putting the script in a live environment.

ALSO - be aware that just adding data from a form into a file on the server, without validating or cleaning, is very very dangerous. I won't go into more detail as that's not what your question asked, but maybe look into that a little as well.

Comment: second line of php needs a semicolon also.